# Search using textbox VB

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I need to search DataGridView by date. If I enter `2/11/2017` in text box, I want grid to show me rows that contain this date. Date column in my DataGridView is named `AppointmentDate` and is created in SQL Server. Type of this column is only date.

I saw this, but I am using Entity Framework model, I don't know how to realize it.

```
    dgvPacientet.CurrentCell = Nothing
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvPacientet.Rows
        row.Visible = row.Cells("Dt_terminit").Value = txtData.Text
        If row.Visible Then found = True
    Next
    If Not found Then MsgBox("Item not found")`
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply show or hide the rows that contain the text you want.

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Nothing
Dim found as Boolean = false
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
   Row.Visible = Not IsDBNull(row.Cells("DT_Terminit").Value) andalso row.Cells("DT_Terminit").Value = TextBox5.Text  
   If Row.Visible then found = true
Next
If Not found Then MsgBox("Item not found")
```

However you really need to parse that textbox to make sure it is a date first and if that cell contains a true Date, you need to convert the test into a date.

```
 Dim DT As Date
 If Not Date.TryParse(TextBox5.Text, DT) Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a date") '<-- remove this line if searching on the fly... (as you enter text)
    Exit Sub
 End If

 DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Nothing

 Dim found As Boolean = False
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    Row.Visible = Not IsDBNull(row.Cells("DT_Terminit").Value) andalso row.Cells("DT_Terminit").Value =DT
    If row.Visible Then found = True
 Next
 If Not found Then MsgBox("Item not found")
```

Comment: it says  Row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made invisible.

Comment: YOu likely need to clear the current cell first... see updated code.

Comment: it doesn't let me to write the date. I start to enter the date and as soon as i enter just 2 it says to me please enter a date.

Comment: OH.. you are calling that search each time you change the text in the search box... in that case get rid of the "Please enter a date" message box line and just exit till it IS a valid date.

Comment: im so sorry but it's not working . When i enter a number it says item not found. My date column is named Dt_terminit and as i mentioned this column is created in sql server , Type only date. This column gets its value by a datetimepicker and i want to search these dates by textbox.

Comment: Sigh.. would be nice if you gave people this information up front... try it now.

Comment: see the updated code , i tried but not , if i try with (Dt_terminit).value=txtData.text it says cannot convert Date to String. I tried (Dt_terminit).value.ToString=txtData.text but not as soon as i enter just a number it says item not found, i dont know what to do

Comment: I'm confused.. in your question you say the column is named AppointmentDate (<which I changed the answer to) but in your text it's Dt_terminit.....

Comment: It may also be a data error.... Are ALL the fields an actual date... if not you need to test for that.

Comment: i said AppointmentDate cause Dt_terminit in your language means AppointmentDate. My gridview contains information about patients like Name,Surname,Dt_terminit,Diagnose etc. I fill these informations and click insert to insert the patient in datagridview. To set the dt_terminit value i select a datetimepicker value. Now when i write in text box a date i want those patients whose "Dt_terminit" is equal with the date i write in the textbox.

Comment: YOu did not answer my last question. Id Dt_Terminit always set or does it start out blank.

Comment: ANyhow.. I added a test for dbnull.IF it still does not work, break on the "row.visible =" line and see what the cell content really is.

Comment: Dt_terminit when i open the form is always date.now. I tried also with dbNull but not as soon as i enter something it says item not found

Comment: You really need to look at it in the debugger... check out the columns and their data on a breakpoint and figure out what is really happening. I can't debug it for you from here.

Comment: give me your email and i'll sent you a photo of my form and you will understand what i need. Because of my reputation i cant post photos here

Comment: I don't do that sorry. I understand what you are tyring to do... you just need to figure out what you are really doing... Use breakpoints and LOOK.

Comment: Personally this approach is not filtering the rows that are in the `DataGridView`. A more fluent approach would be filtering a `DataView` and set that as the source to the `DataGridView`. Also if you turn on Option Strict you would see some issues in the solution provided, for example: `row.Cells("DT_Terminit").Value =DT`, you are comparing an object to a Date object...

Comment: Yes. I was in two minds on this answer too @Zaggler. The row hide method is very fast though compared to per character queries.